# Should I use the actual page number, or the PDF's page number in a parenthetical citation?

Tags: citations, mla

Let's say I have a PDF, and I want to cite something on page 2 of the PDF. Would I want to use the actual page number listed (page 724 apparently), or the page number of the PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual page number. Your pdf has been made from another publication. Somebody may have access to the original. They want the actual page number. Also, another pdf made from the same publication may have different page numbers.

Comment: not sure what 'made from another publication' means, but post-arxiv, PDF is the primary format for a lot of publications. guessing this is true in other domains as well. also people are citing by doi / URL, i.e. digital-first.

is there a standard way to list both page numbers? 'pdf p2 / printed p724'? from a usability perspective, having the PDF page # makes it way easier to locate the citation.

Comment: Many PDFs which have to cited have been taken from a book or journal. In the question it says 'page 724 apparently'. Yes, having the PDF page number makes it easier to locate if you have the same PDF. It is useless if you don't.

Answer (score -1):

I do like the idea of having a Pdf p2 / printed p724 type of setup to clarify what you're referring to. In fact, I wish PDF pages were referred to by another term, like "sheet". That way, you could say "Sheet 346 (Page 58 of Document X, found in Appendix B of this Report)".

In response to "having the PDF page number makes it easier to locate if you have the same PDF. It is useless if you don't." - If you don't have the same PDF, you wouldn't have the callout "Pdf p2 / printed p724" anywhere, so there's no problem, true?

Say you have a report with several appendices each containing a document with dozens of printed page numbers, it would be quite convenient to know how far to scroll down without having to try and figure out where the appendix is first, and then locating the printed page number.